# XSLT : Copy nodes to another node while iterating

Tags: xml, xslt

I have currently this type of request. The problem is that the existing code can manage only one block of Attribute. I need to cut the attribute block and create N new blocks.

Input :

```
<Request>
<Attributes>
    <Attribute>
        <Complimentary>
            Test1
        </Complimentary>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <Complimentary>
            Test2
        </Complimentary>
    </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
        <Complimentary>
            TestN
        </Complimentary>
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
</Request>
```

Output :

```
<Request>
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute>
            <Complimentary>
                Test1
            </Complimentary>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute>
            <Complimentary>
                Test2
            </Complimentary>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute>
            <Complimentary>
                TestN
            </Complimentary>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</Request>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If I read this correctly, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Attributes">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Attribute">
    <Attributes>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </Attributes>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```